# How to clean log file?

Tags: logs

Is there a better way to clean the log file? I usually delete the old logfile and create a new logfile and I am looking for a shorter type/bash/command program. How can I use an alias?

Answer (score 359, accepted):

```
> logfile
```

or

```
cat /dev/null > logfile
```

or

```
true | tee logfile
```

(fell free to substitute `false` or any other command that produces no output, like e.g. `:` does in `bash`) if you want to be more eloquent, will all empty `logfile` (actually they will truncate it to zero size).

If you want to know how long it "takes", you may use

```
dd if=/dev/null of=logfile
```

(which is the same as `dd if=/dev/null > logfile`, by the way)

You can also use

```
truncate --size 0 logfile
```

(or `truncate -s 0 logfile`) to be perfectly explicit or, if you don't want to,

```
rm logfile
```

(in which case you are relying on the common behaviour that applications usually do recreate a logfile if it doesn't exist already).

However, since logfiles are usually useful, you might want to compress and save a copy. While you could do that with your own script, it is a good idea to at least try using an existing working solution, in this case `logrotate`, which can do exactly that and is reasonably configurable.

Should you need to do it for several files, the safe way is

```
truncate -s 0 file1 file2 ...
```

or

```
> file1 > file2 ...
```

Some shells (`zsh`) also allow one to specify several redirection targets.

This works (at least in `bash`) since it creates all the redirections required although only the last one will catch any input (or none in this case). The `tee` example with several files should work in any case (given your `tee` does know how to handle several output files)

Of course, the good old shell loop would work as well:

```sh
for f in file1 file2 ... ; do
    # pick your favourite emptying method
done
```

although it will be much slower due to the command being run separately for each file. That may be helped by using `find`:

```
find <criteria matching required files> \
    -exec <command capable of zeroing several files> {} \+
```

or

```
find <criteria matching required files> -delete
```

Comment: What about shred? Can it zero my log files?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? `shred` will destroy the data, so that it will be hard to recover them even with forensic tools (from a spinning plate HDD, that is), but it will take it ages (it overwrites the blocks used by the file several times). `> logfile` will just truncate it (very quickly).

Comment: @Phpdna logrotate has a `shred` option. Use logrotate.

Comment: I don't have much space left. Is this something new?

Comment: @LukeGriffiths that will actually truncate the file as well, for it will be opened by the shell before the command is spawned with the `O_TRUNC` flag. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators for more details.

Comment: You are correct @peterph.  I'm deleting my previous comment as it contains incorrect information.  I would edit it, but it can't be edited so I'm opting for deletion.  My previous comment said: "If you want to keep the last N lines of the file you can use `tail -n 10000 logfile > logfile`".  Which is incorrect; don't do it!

Comment: for Freebsd: `truncate -s 0 logfile`

Comment: How can do it to multiple files? `$ cat /dev/null > *.log
-bash: *.log: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: @SiminJie see updated answer